# Upload images to imgur from shutter as Guest doesn't work

Tags: upload, shutter

I'm the only one with problems to upload files to imgur as Guest? It's a new installation.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: maybe its a bug on imgur's side?

Comment: I haven't been able to upload to imgur via shutter in a long while too. I'm guessing imgur changed their API. Please file a bug against shutter. Thanks!

Comment: @patrick perhaps... I don't know

Comment: @Seth do you know how I can report a bug in shutter?

Comment: @JorgeB. The link is in the hold description :) http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug

Comment: https://code.launchpad.net/~systemdisc/shutter/imgur-fix/+merge/313977

Comment: To solve the problem: https://bugs.launchpad.net/shutter/+bug/1565048/comments/14